# Why this code stuck node.js - Bug on Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, unicode, infinite-loop

I'm trying to run this regex but it stuck my console. Why?

```
var str = "Шедевры православной музыки - 20 золотых православных песен";
str.match(/^(([\u00C0-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF]+[^a-z\u00C0-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF]*)+) [a-z]+[^\u00C0-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF]*$/i);
```

Comment: What do you mean by stuck? You enter this in he console and it freezes?

Comment: It just causes [catastrophic backtracking](https://regex101.com/r/eT6gL3/1) due to `(([\u00C0-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF]+[^a-z\u00C0-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF]*)+)` part. More details on [catastrophic backtracking can be found here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html). What are the actual requirements for the regex?

Comment: Are you looking for [`^([\u00C0-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF]+(?:[^a-z\u00C0-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF]+[\u00C0-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF]+)*) [a-z]+[^\u00C0-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/eT6gL3/2)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your regex causes [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) (see [a demo of your regex here](https://regex101.com/r/eT6gL3/1)) due to `(([\u00C0-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF]+[^a-z\u00C0-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF]*)+)` part. As `[^a-z\u00C0-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF]*` can match zero characters, you basically have a classical `(a+)+`-like pattern (cf: `([\u00C0-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF]+)+`) that causes backtracking issue.

To get rid of it, you need to make sure the subpatterns are *compulsory* inside the grouping, and apply a `*` quantifier to the whole grouping:

```
^([\u00C0-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF]+(?:[^a-z\u00C0-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF]+[\u00C0-\u1‌​FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF]+)*) [a-z]+[^\u00C0-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF]*$
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eT6gL3/2)

Here, `[\u00C0-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF]+(?:[^a-z\u00C0-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF]+[\u00C0-\u1‌​FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF]+)*` matches:

- `[\u00C0-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF]+` - one or more character from `[\u00C0-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF]` ranges
- `(?:[^a-z\u00C0-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF]+[\u00C0-\u1‌​FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF]+)*` - zero or more sequences of:

  - `[^a-z\u00C0-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF]+` - one or more characters other than those from the `a-z\u00C0-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF` ranges
  - `[\u00C0-\u1‌​FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF]+` - one or more characters from the `\u00C0-\u1‌​FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF` ranges.